# How do I group value in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

My current db structure `company`

```
ID  company 
-----------------
1   Company A
2   Company B
3   Company B
4   Company B
```

How do I make a SQL statement to group company according to current get value. Example `$get['company_name'] = 'Company B'`

```
$sql = $db->query('
       SELECT * FROM company 
       WHERE company = "'.secure($get['company_name']).'"
');
 while ($data = $db->fetch($sql))
```

Results should be display on while

```
Company B
Company B
Company B
```

Let me know..

Comment: warning your code is susceptible to SQL injection.

Comment: Do you really need grouping, because _"Results should be display on while"_ asks otherwise?! Is that how you want it to be, or you want it to return just one `Company B`?

Comment: Do you want to *group* your results, or just retrieve only results with some given company name? That's different than grouping.

Comment: Aside from replacing "*" with "company" your query already does what you said you want.

Comment: do you want results other than Company B?  and just have them grouped

Comment: So what is your code result now ?

Comment: Currently only display 1 result. I want to display the `Company B` 3 times.

Comment: hmmm.. my fault GROUP will group it to be 1.. LOL.. sorry guys..

Comment: @Joe: If the current query returns one result, then you either are using `GROUP BY` clause already and not showing it to us, OR you have only one record with the value on the `company` column equal to `Company B`. Which one is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = $db->query("
       SELECT company FROM company 
       WHERE company = '".secure($get['company_name'])."'"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think it has to be with GROUP BY name or something like this. Here this link for more info :http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlgroupby.php

Hope this helps,

Etienne